# Converting Decimal to Hexadecimal number using MODULO DIVISION method

Tags: postgresql, hex, decimal, modulus

I am  converting Decimal number

> 42541956123769884636017138956568135808

to hexadecimal number

> 20014860486000000000000000008880

My converted value is `20014860486000000000000000019980`

My Postgresql function for conversion is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ipv6_dec_hex(ip_number numeric)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

    ip  int :=null;
    ip1 character varying := '';
    ip2 character varying;

BEGIN
        while(ip_number != 0)
        LOOP
            ip = trunc(mod(ip_number,16));
            ip_number = trunc(ip_number/16);
            ip1:=ip1||to_hex(ip);
            raise notice 'ip is %',ip;
            raise notice 'ip_number is %',ip_number;

        END LOOP;
        ip2:=reverse(ip1);

        return ip2;
END;
   $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I am using modulo-remainder method. so I am taking modulus for the given number with `16` and divide given decimal number by `16` for consecutive hexadecimal number conversions. While taking modulus in first iteration I am getting

> `0` as remainder as last digit of hexadecimal number `20014860486000000000000000008880`
>
> and next dividend is `2658872257735617789751071184785508488`

In second iteration taking modulus of `2658872257735617789751071184785508488` getting

> `8` as remainder second from last digit of hexadecimal number `20014860486000000000000000008880`
>
> and next dividend is `166179516108476111859441949049094281`

In third iteration taking modulus of `166179516108476111859441949049094281` getting

> `9` as remainder but `8` is the exact hexadecimal digit to come in
>   third from last digit of hexadecimal number `20014860486000000000000000008880`

If the above dividend value is `166179516108476111859441949049094280`
instead of `166179516108476111859441949049094281` then i will get the remainder value as `8` . How could i get the exact hexadecimal value `20014860486000000000000000008880` instead of `20014860486000000000000000019980`

Comment: hmm, `encode(int8send(4122324523),'hex')`  works for numbers that smaller than 2^127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say this you'll get floating-point division, and that will give a loss of precision.

```
ip_number = trunc(ip_number/16);
```

Say this instead

```
ip_number = div(ip_number,16);
```

[docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html)

full source after edit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ipv6_dec_hex(ip_number numeric)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

    ip  int :=null;
    ip1 character varying := '';
    ip2 character varying;

BEGIN
        while(ip_number != 0)
        LOOP
            ip = mod(ip_number,16);
            ip_number = div(ip_number,16);
            ip1:=ip1||to_hex(ip);
            raise notice 'ip is %',ip;
            raise notice 'ip_number is %',ip_number;

        END LOOP;
        ip2:=reverse(ip1);

        return ip2;
END;
   $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

select ipv6_dec_hex(42541956123769884636017138956568135808)
   ='20014860486000000000000000008880';
```